# How can i convert comma separated strings to lower case using c#

Tags: c#, string, lowercase

I would like to convert the string stored as (STATUS,STATE) to lower case.
Here is my code :

```
attrVal_TestCondition = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value;
```

where output for `attrVal_TestCondition` is `(STATE,STATUS)` and i would like to convert this to lower case.
So i want my string to look like this :

```
(state,status)
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to convert string to lower case do:

```
str.ToLower();
```

and in your case:

```
Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value.ToLower();
```

or

```
Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value.ToString().ToLower();
```

Comment: well if i tried it then i am not able to do it as it showing me a error.

Comment: @user2778482 what type is "attrVal_TestCondition"?

Comment: @user2778482 you should accept answers, not just here but in general, i see you did not accepted answers on other questions, you can accept answers by pressing the "v" next to the score

Comment: @user2778482 glad i could be of service

Answer (score 0):

In case No Idea For Name's answer is not blindingly obvious enough for you,

```
attrVal_TestCondition = Update_Bugs[m].Attributes["TestCondition"].Value.ToLowerCase();
```

That the string is comma separated has no bearing on anything. You are essentially asking how to lower case a string. What the string contains is not relevant.

Comment: Well the output is (STATE,STATUS) and i would like to convert it as (state,status)